# Connecting to MySQL server ... Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 in mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, archlinux, chromebook

when i try to login in mysql-workbench i get this error

> Connecting to MySQL server ...
> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

[image: image description here]

looks my database status of mariadb

```
MariaDB [(none)]> status;
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.5-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          13
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.6.5-MariaDB Arch Linux
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
UNIX socket:            /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 55 min 13 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 7  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 17  Open tables: 10  Queries per second avg: 0.002
--------------
```

Answer (score 0):

check your database status is activing

Comment: yes its active.

Comment: set bind-address=0.0.0.0

Comment: problem that when i try to do that it say my.cnf dont exist. I dont know how to create my that i anciently delete because in my first installation it was big mess so i delete all file from that dir after i reinstall it works prefect now.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench is a client tool for MySQL. You are running a Maria server, which might use a different protocol.